# How to count activities when a Lead is converted

Tags: lead-conversion, activities

Is there a way to count the activities when a LEad is already converted.

I could create a report when the leads are converted by adding isConverted is true. However is there a way to count the acitivities for the given lead that is converted?

Comment: I see you've tagged your question with `salesforce-communities`. I'm trying to understand the context of your question and don't have a clue what communities has to do with it. Is this a reporting question? Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Since you cannot view a converted Lead in the UI, you're pretty much stuck with either running a report for the specific Lead or using a SOQL query. What is the goal of using this data? That could indicate which solution(s) will be best.